# Ambiguous call of method

Tags: c#, ambiguity

I have the following code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.M(null);
    }
}

class A
{
    public void M(int? i)
    { }

    public void M(string s)
    { }
}
```

And I have an error, because the call is ambiguous. I need to change the call of M method without adding any lines to Main method and accessing class A so that it became correct. Could someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Define correct ? which method should be called ?

Comment: which method you want to invoke

Answer (score 3):

You can use explicit cast:

```
A a = new A();
a.M((string)null);
```

or

```
a.M((int?)null);
```

to help the compiler of picking the right overload. Note that C# compiler can't determine what method overload to call based on `null` literal.

For advanced topic consider Eric's article [What is the type of the null literal?](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/25/what-is-the-type-of-the-null-literal/)

**edit:**

since your argument names are different, you can use named arguments, which are avaliable since **C# 4.0**:

```
a.M(i : null);
```

or

```
a.M(s : null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cast, or the [`default` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx), or for `int?`, `new int?()` (which, due to [how Nullable types work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx), is also the same as `null`). You could also use [named parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) to disambiguate. Or, of course, if you were ok with adding another line, you could declare your value in a variable and pass that in.

```
// these call the int? overload
a.M(default(int?));
a.M((int?)null);
a.M(new int?());
a.M(i: null);
int? i = null;
a.M(i);

// these call the string overload
a.M(default(string));
a.M((string)null);
a.M(s: null);
string s = null;
a.M(s);
```

Comment: And rounding out the list you could also use `new int?()`.

Comment: @EricLippert for complete list: `a.M(i : null)` since argument names are different

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: Good one!

Comment: I like it. :) I've added both of these. Are there any other ways that come to mind, besides variations on the "pass a variable in" approach?

Comment: I can't think of any. Maybe `a.M(null as string)`, but it's just a variation of cast in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you cannot overload the member M this way if you cannot alter existing call sites.

Presumably you are adding one of the two methods and can alter the call sites for calls to the new method. Change the name of the method for those new call sites to use.

Comment: The question says that he can't add new lines of code to the call sites, not that he can't change them, so the other answers are still technically correct.

Comment: @Servy I read "can't add new lines" to mean "can't modify any lines" because it doesn't make sense to be able to modify but not add lines. Is there some kind of line count limit that must be avoided?

Comment: `I need to change the call of M method without adding any lines to Main method and accessing class A so that it became correct` this is as vague as I can imagine. Where in my answer I have added lines?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Read "the call of M" as "the signature of M" and "without adding any lines" as "without modifying any lines" (as per the argument above). I agree that my interpretation of the poorly worded question is subject to debate, but my money is on that interpretation.